# How Look at Oplog in Mongodb with Sharding

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I've looked through documentation that says the oplog is a stored collection on the local db. When I attempt to `show collections` after `use local`, I receive the error "can't use 'local' database through mongos. Error code: 13644. This seems to be related to having sharding. I am attempting to look at the oplog to see what exactly it says when I insert a specific document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sharding router (mongos) does not contain any data, so there isn't a oplog. Connect to the primary on the shard that received the insert. The oplog is the local.oplog.rs collection.